# Limits of functions in the Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis

For any function in the [Schwartz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) $\phi\in {\mathcal{S}({\bf R})}$, what can one say for the following two limits?
$$\begin{align}
1.& \qquad\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\phi(-x)-\phi(x)\right)[\log x]\\
2.& \qquad\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\phi(-x)-\phi(x)\right)[\log x]
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I hope I understand what you mean)
$\phi$ decreases at $\infty$ faster than any power - so the 1st limit is surely $0$. It is also (even infinitely) differentiable, in particular $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (\phi(x)-\phi(-x))/x$ exists, so the 2nd limit is $0$ too.

Comment: @Theo&Jack: I have to say I'm confused by the notation - what is inside the log? Only $x$ (as I supposed), or everything?

Comment: I think now the formula is clear.

Comment: Yes, it is and now I understand the answer as well.